# Dynamic attribute on mouseenter/mouseleave event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to set the `autoplay` attribute depending on the [mouse events that 'vueper-slide' is firing](https://antoniandre.github.io/vueper-slides/#vueper-slide--events).

So, on `mouseenter`, autoplay should be set to `true` and on `mouseleave` it should be set to `false`. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem if I had a static number of slides. The problem is that the amount of these 'vueper-slides' is dynamic, as you can see in the code below.

Does someone know how to solve this?

Here's the Vue file:

```js
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row v-for="(project, i) in projects" :key="'row-'+i" no-gutters>
            <v-col v-for="(images, j) in project" :key="`col-` + j + i" cols="4">
                <vueper-slides 
                    fade 
                    :touchable="false" 
                    :autoplay="true" 
                    duration="1000" 
                    :pauseOnHover="false" 
                    :slideRatio="9/16"
                >
                    <vueper-slide
                        v-for="(img, k) in images"
                        :key="`vueper-`+k+i+j"
                        :image="require(`@/${img}`)"
                    />
                </vueper-slides>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { VueperSlides, VueperSlide } from 'vueperslides'
import 'vueperslides/dist/vueperslides.css'

export default {
  props: ['projects'],

  components: { VueperSlides, VueperSlide }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is that not what `pauseOnHover` is for?